# MySql query sum rows based on other column value

Tags: mysql

hey i have really weird logic can some one help me to write query. I want to sum all prices for regOption where regOption  also have xnCoupon (coupon and regOption Share same entry_id). In this exaple wanted amount is 139.

```
|id         |trans_id|  entry_id    |type     | Price
------------------------------------------------------ 
|43575855   |24419612|  26898343    |regOption|  139         
|43575856   |24419612|  26898343    |xnCoupon |  50

|43575857   |24419612|  26898346    |regOption|  139         
|43575858   |24419612|  26898346    |Tshirt   |  10
```

in second example wanted amount would be 278

```
|id         |trans_id|  entry_id    |type     | Price
------------------------------------------------------ 
|43575855   |24419612|  26898343    |regOption|  139         
|43575856   |24419612|  26898343    |xnCoupon |  50

|43575857   |24419612|  26898346    |regOption|  139         
|43575858   |24419612|  26898346    |xnCoupon |  50
```

My try is like this

`Select sum(price) FROM table where type ='regOption' AND (something)` to check is regOption with related with xnCoupon by same entry_id?

Can someone help me with logic, any help is welcomed

Comment: any idea? i could help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(price) 
FROM table 
WHERE type = 'regOption' 
AND entry_id IN
(
    SELECT entry_id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE type = 'xnCoupon'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you are looking - this statement sums the price of regOption types with corresponding xnCoupon for each transaction and gives a grand total.

```
select ifnull(reg.trans_id,'<<TOTAL>>') as trans_id,
       sum(reg.price)
  from `table` reg
  join `table` xnc
        on (   xnc.entry_id = reg.entry_id
           and reg.type = 'regOption'
           and xnc.type = 'xnCoupon')
 group by reg.trans_id with rollup;
```